# I am unsure where to start for part (iii). It provides a hint to try and find the constant a first but I am unsure how to do this.

Tags: derivatives, polynomials, constants

> B.2. An enthusiastic theoretical physics student is working on a numerical algorithm for finding roots to higher order polynomials.
> (i) Show that if $(x - \alpha)^2$ is a factor of the polynomial $p(x)$, then $p'(\alpha) = 0$. [2]
> (ii) Show a corresponding result if $(x - a)^4$ is a factor of $p(x)$. [4]
> (iii) Hence, given that the polynomial
> $$x^6-7x^5+15x^4-40x^2+\kappa x+\lambda$$
> has a factor of the form $(x - \alpha)^4$, find $\kappa$ and $\lambda$. [14]
> Hint: Find $\alpha$.

The question, as mentioned above part (i) and (ii) seem simple enough,
but I am unsure where to start for part (iii). It provides a hint to try and find the constant a first but I am unsure how to do this. Any guidance would be massively appreciated. (The University don't provide their own answer schemes)

Comment: Hint: If $(x - \alpha)^2$ is a factor of $p(x)$, then $p(x)$ can be written as $p(x) = (x - \alpha)^2 q(x)$ for some polynomial $q(x)$. Can you take it from here?

Comment: (ii) is $p'''(\alpha)=0$, but $p'''(x)$ in (iii) is $x\cdot$quadratic. (namely, [$(x^6 - 7 x^5 + 15 x^4)''' = 60 x (2 x^2 - 7 x + 6)$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28x%5E6%E2%88%927x%5E5%2B15x%5E4%29%27%27%27) )

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin so from that quadratic you get the three values of x where p'''(x) = 0, but if I am being honest I'm still fairly unsure where to go from here.

Comment: @sudeep5221 I am afraid that I still feel a bit lost with this particular question.

Comment: Then $p'(\alpha)=0$ and $p(\alpha)=0$ where $\alpha=\frac32,2$ that leads to [$\kappa=48,\,\lambda=-16$ for $\alpha=2$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E6%E2%88%927*x%5E5%2B15*x%5E4%E2%88%9240*x%5E2%2Bk*x%2Bl%3D0%2C+%28x%5E6%E2%88%927*x%5E5%2B15*x%5E4%E2%88%9240*x%5E2%2Bk*x%2Bl%29%27%3D0%2C+x%3D2) and $\kappa = \frac{393}{8}, \lambda = -\frac{1143}{64}$ for $\alpha = \frac32$

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin ahhh ok, for some reason I had it in my head that I could only have one value for both k and Lambda, but that makes a lot of sense. Thank you and i really appreciate the help. :)

Comment: You're welcome)